# What is the easiest way to flatten nested JSON data in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file in which some columns contain nested JSON data. How can I read this into a pandas data frame and flatten the nested data?

The data looks like this -

```
#some columns contain data in a dictionary
df['device'][0]
'{"browser": "Firefox", "browserVersion": "not available in demo dataset", "browserSize": "not available in demo dataset", "operatingSystem": "Windows", "operatingSystemVersion": "not available in demo dataset", "isMobile": false, "mobileDeviceBranding": "not available in demo dataset", "mobileDeviceModel": "not available in demo dataset", "mobileInputSelector": "not available in demo dataset", "mobileDeviceInfo": "not available in demo dataset", "mobileDeviceMarketingName": "not available in demo dataset", "flashVersion": "not available in demo dataset", "language": "not available in demo dataset", "screenColors": "not available in demo dataset", "screenResolution": "not available in demo dataset", "deviceCategory": "desktop"}'

#and some contain dictionary in a list
df['hits'][0]
"[{'hitNumber': '1', 'time': '0', 'hour': '17', 'minute': '0', 'isInteraction': True, 'isEntrance': True, 'isExit': True, 'referer': 'https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=water+bottle&ie=utf-8&num=100&oe=utf-8&hl=en&gl=GB&uule=w+CAIQIFISCamRx0IRO1oCEXoliDJDoPjE&glp=1&gws_rd=cr&fg=1', 'page': {'pagePath': '/google+redesign/bags/water+bottles+and+tumblers', 'hostname': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com', 'pageTitle': 'Water Bottles & Tumblers | Drinkware | Google Merchandise Store', 'pagePathLevel1': '/google+redesign/', 'pagePathLevel2': '/bags/', 'pagePathLevel3': '/water+bottles+and+tumblers', 'pagePathLevel4': ''}, 'transaction': {'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'item': {'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'appInfo': {'screenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/google+redesign/bags/water+bottles+and+tumblers', 'landingScreenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/google+redesign/bags/water+bottles+and+tumblers', 'exitScreenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/google+redesign/bags/water+bottles+and+tumblers', 'screenDepth': '0'}, 'exceptionInfo': {'isFatal': True}, 'product': [{'productSKU': 'GGOEGDHC074099', 'v2ProductName': 'Google 17oz Stainless Steel Sport Bottle', 'v2ProductCategory': 'Home/Drinkware/Water Bottles and Tumblers/', 'productVariant': '(not set)', 'productBrand': '(not set)', 'productPrice': '23990000', 'localProductPrice': '23990000', 'isImpression': True, 'customDimensions': [], 'customMetrics': [], 'productListName': 'Category', 'productListPosition': '1'}, {'productSKU': 'GGOEGDHQ015399', 'v2ProductName': '26 oz Double Wall Insulated Bottle', 'v2ProductCategory': 'Home/Drinkware/Water Bottles and Tumblers/', 'productVariant': '(not set)', 'productBrand': '(not set)', 'productPrice': '24990000', 'localProductPrice': '24990000', 'isImpression': True, 'customDimensions': [], 'customMetrics': [], 'productListName': 'Category', 'productListPosition': '2'}, {'productSKU': 'GGOEYDHJ056099', 'v2ProductName': '22 oz YouTube Bottle Infuser', 'v2ProductCategory': 'Home/Drinkware/Water Bottles and Tumblers/', 'productVariant': '(not set)', 'productBrand': '(not set)', 'productPrice': '4990000', 'localProductPrice': '4990000', 'isImpression': True, 'customDimensions': [], 'customMetrics': [], 'productListName': 'Category', 'productListPosition': '3'}, {'productSKU': 'GGOEGAAX0074', 'v2ProductName': 'Google 22 oz Water Bottle', 'v2ProductCategory': 'Home/Drinkware/Water Bottles and Tumblers/', 'productVariant': '(not set)', 'productBrand': '(not set)', 'productPrice': '2990000', 'localProductPrice': '2990000', 'isImpression': True, 'customDimensions': [], 'customMetrics': [], 'productListName': 'Category', 'productListPosition': '4'}], 'promotion': [], 'eCommerceAction': {'action_type': '0', 'step': '1'}, 'experiment': [], 'customVariables': [], 'customDimensions': [], 'customMetrics': [], 'type': 'PAGE', 'social': {'socialNetwork': '(not set)', 'hasSocialSourceReferral': 'No', 'socialInteractionNetworkAction': ' : '}, 'contentGroup': {'contentGroup1': '(not set)', 'contentGroup2': 'Bags', 'contentGroup3': '(not set)', 'contentGroup4': '(not set)', 'contentGroup5': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup1': '(entrance)', 'previousContentGroup2': '(entrance)', 'previousContentGroup3': '(entrance)', 'previousContentGroup4': '(entrance)', 'previousContentGroup5': '(entrance)', 'contentGroupUniqueViews2': '1'}, 'dataSource': 'web', 'publisher_infos': []}]"
```

I am trying to solve it for more than 5 hours but couldn't able to solve it. Can anyone help me with this? For convenience, I am also including the small [CSV file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FV-xR7dqF591aI8tcVJYecmHCQpF7TgB/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks.

Comment: What should happen if the value is empty?, for example `customDimensions` in row 8 from the CSV sample

Comment: @jcaliz for the empty values both the index and value keys will have null values. like {"index: 'NULL', "value": 'NULL'}

Comment: You might want to share a good example, because some cells do not meet the json structure, e.g. second row of `hits`, I see a problem in the way the quotes are being assigned.

Comment: @jcaliz previously I was getting a double quote error when working with the file so I changed all the single quotes to double-quotes. I think it might be the problem. I have updated the code and also included the original raw CSV file link which is not modified.

Comment: Great, do you mind posting the expected output for the cases where you have multiple jsons? for example `hits` second row.

Comment: Things are worse than that. Some lines can contain nested jsons containing lists with more than one element. In that case, you may want to duplicate the row per each element of the nested list...

Comment: @jcaliz   Some rows of hits columns are corrupted, when the data was extracted. I wasn't aware of it before. Corrupted rows can be deleted, it won't impact much. And thanks for all the efforts, I really appreciate it.